# Clases y Constructores en Java

Tags: java, clase, constructor

En la uni estamos "aprendiendo" sobre clases y constructores, sin embargo los apuntes que nos envian no son bastante claros. Por ahora tengo este pequeño programa:

```
package ejerUnidad1;

public class Ejercicio01 {

    public class Fraccion { //clase Fraccion
        int numerador;
        int denominador;

        public Fraccion() {//constructor Fraccion
            this.numerador=1;
            this.denominador=1;
        }

        /*public Fraccion(int n,int d) {
            this.numerador=n;
            this.denominador=d;
        }*/

        public void imprimir() {//metodo para imprimir
            System.out.println(this.numerador+"/"+this.denominador+"="+this.numerador/this.denominador);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Fraccion frax=new Fraccion();
        frax.imprimir();
    }
}
```

Sin embargo aun no se como usarlo, el programa principal me da error en el `new Fraccion();` y quiero saber que estoy haciendo mal.
Tambien quisiera saber la diferencia entre metodos de instancia y de clase (estáticos).

Comment: Ya... ¿Qué error da?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como mencionas que apenas están aprendiendo sobre clases y constructores, es probable que no te hayas dado cuenta que tienes la clase fracción dentro de la clase Ejercicio01. El uso de clases anidadas está un poco más avanzado para lo que dices que podrías saber del tema, entonces no mencionaré algo más que esté en otras respuestas.

Te sugiero eliminar la línea en donde defines la clase Ejercicio01 y su corchete de cierre, de forma que te quede así:

```
 public class Fraccion { //clase Fraccion
    int numerador;
    int denominador;

    public Fraccion() {//constructor Fraccion
        this.numerador=1;
        this.denominador=1;
    }

    /*public Fraccion(int n,int d) {
        this.numerador=n;
        this.denominador=d;
    }*/

    public void imprimir() {//metodo para imprimir
        System.out.println(this.numerador+"/"+this.denominador+"="+this.numerador/this.denominador);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
         Fraccion frax=new Fraccion();
         frax.imprimir();
    }
}
```

Sobre tu duda del modificador static, es una palabra que puedes colocar delante de variables o métodos, y su función es crear miembros que pertenezcan a la clase y no a una instancia de la clase (tal vez con el ejemplo esto quede más claro).

Tenemos una clase Usuario que tiene un miembro static llamado 'usuarios'. Cuando creamos un objeto de esta clase, el valor de usuarios se incrementa en 1.

```
class Usuario{
     static int usuarios = 0;
     Usuario(){
          usuarios++;
     }
}
```

Luego tenemos la clase donde vamos a probar su funcionamiento:

```
public class Ejemplo{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     Usuario luis = new Usuario();
     Usuario ana = new Usuario();
     System.out.println("Hay " + Usuario.usuarios + " usuarios");
 }
}
```

El resultado que se mostrará es "Hay 2 usuarios", pero nota como para utiliza su valor no fue necesario utilizar un objeto de la clase Usuario. Al declarar la variable usuarios como static le estas indicando al compilador que la variable no pertenece a un objeto de la clase Usuario, lo que hace que no se inicialice cuando se crea un objeto, sino cuando se carga una clase en memoria durante la ejecución.

Para los métodos estáticos el caso es igual: para utilizarlos no es necesario crear un objeto de la clase en la que están declarados, puedes probar con la clase Math:

```
public class Ejemplo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println("PI es " + Math.PI);
          System.out.println("El coseno de 120 es " + Math.cos(120));
     }
}
```

Nota como para usar el valor de PI o el método cos() no es necesario crear un objeto de la clase Math, sino que se accede a ellos solo con el nombre de su clase.

Answer (score 1):

El error que estarías teniendo en el escenario actual sería el siguiente o parecido:

> non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context

El motivo es porque desde el método `main` que es estático, intentas crear una instancia de `Fraccion`, pero esa clase no ha sido declarada como estática.

La palabra clave `static` modifica el ciclo de vida de un miembro o un método perteneciente a una clase. Los miembros o métodos declarados estáticos **se crean en el momento en que se carga la clase**. Mientras que un método o miembro no estático **se crea solo cuando la clase es instanciada**, por ejemplo, utilizando `new()`. En breves palabras, se dice que los miembros estáticos pertenecen a la clase en sí mientras que los no estáticos pertenecen a la instancia de la clase.<sup>1</sup>.

Dado que en Java, el método `main`, que es el punto de entrada de un programa, tiene que ser definido como estático (precisamente para entrar a un programa no necesitas crear una instancia de la clase que contiene `main`), en tu escenario, no puedes acceder desde `main` a la clase `Fraccion` porque esta no es estática.

### Soluciones posibles

En el apartado **Shadowing**, donde [Java Tutorials explica las clases anidadas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), te pone un ejemplo sobre cómo resolver este problema. Consiste en:

- Crear desde `main` una instancia de la clase `Ejercicio01`
- Usar esa instancia para crear la instancia de la clase `Fraccion`

Con esos dos pasos solventas la prohibición de acceder directamente un miembro no estático desde un contexto estático.

Si aplicas esa solución el código quedaría así:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Ejercicio01 mEjercicio01 = new Ejercicio01();
    /*
       *Esto funciona también así: Fraccion frax = mEjercicio01.new Fraccion();
       *pero por claridad conviene poner el nombre de la clase contenedora
    */
    Ejercicio01.Fraccion frax = mEjercicio01.new Fraccion();
    frax.imprimir();
}
```

---

Otra solución sería declarar la clase `Fraction` como `static`, entonces podrías acceder a ella desde `main`, porque estarías llamando un miembro estático desde un contexto estático.

En la definición de la clase se pone `static`:

```
   public static class Fraccion { //clase Fraccion
      int numerador;
      int denominador;
      //...
   }
```

Y en el `main` no habría problema en hacer esto:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Fraccion frax = new Fraccion();
    frax.imprimir();
}
```

**PD:** Dado que se trata de un ejercicio, no entraré en la discusión de si conviene o no conviene. Para este caso, te recomiendo que uses soluciones basadas en la documentación y que leas las indicaciones que se dan en ella.

### Notas

1. @AaronDiguila [lo explica aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2559596/5587982) de forma bastante clara con un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

la clase principal se debe llamar igual que el archivo, y no puedes meter una pedazo de una clase dentro de otra, la clase Fraccion la creaste bien, pero estaba dentro de otra.

```
   public class Ejercicio01 { //clase Fraccion
        int numerador;
        int denominador;

        public Ejercicio01() {//constructor Fraccion
            this.numerador=1;
            this.denominador=1;
        }

        /*public Fraccion(int n,int d) {
            this.numerador=n;
            this.denominador=d;
        }*/

        public void imprimir() {//metodo para imprimir
            System.out.println(this.numerador+"/"+this.denominador+"="+this.numerador/this.denominador);
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Ejercicio01 frax=new Ejercicio01();
        frax.imprimir();
    }
}
```

Comment: Pero sí puede haber clases dentro de otra clase, eso se llama [*Clases anidadas*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). Si es el esquema que le dieron para un ejercicio supongo que debería respetarse ese esquema y que la clase `Ejercicio01` contenga a la clase `Fraccion`.

Comment: se puede pero no se recomienda.

Comment: Depende, hay escenarios en los que sí se recomienda usarlas. Lee el apartado *Why Use Nested Classes?* en el enlace de mi anterior comentario. De todos modos es un ejercicio y meterse en un debate sobre si se recomiendan o no sería alejarse del propósito de la pregunta.

Comment: @EduardoDelacruz Si no se recomienda, ¿por qué la clase [Arrays](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L2834) si usa una clase anidada? Si en Java existe la clase anidada es por algo, de lo contrario, no existiera :D